# Trying to figure out what provide does

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following a ruby on rails tutorial and I have the following got in a users view `<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>` just wondering what exactly that is doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should answer your question:

> content_for?
>
> simply checks whether any content has been captured yet using #content_for
>
> Useful to render parts of your layout differently based on what is in your views.

Examples

Perhaps you will use different css in you layout if no #content_for :right_column

```
<%# This is the layout %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <title>My Website</title>
 <%= yield :script %>
</head>
<body class="<%= content_for?(:right_col) ? 'one-column' : 'two-column' %>">
 <%= yield %>
 <%= yield :right_col %>
```

> provide(name, content = nil, &block)
>
> The same as content_for but when used with streaming flushes straight back to the layout. In other words, if you want to concatenate several times to the same buffer when rendering a given template, you should use content_for, if not, use provide to tell the layout to stop looking for more contents.

**Short answer:**
In the Ruby on Rails tutorial the special rails function provide is used to set a different title on each page. Depending on which static_page you are on the title is set accordingly. Further explanation is given in 3.3.3 ("Embedded Ruby") in the Ruby on Rails tutorial book.